# Ratio Test $S = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{9^n}{(n + 1)*2^{(2n - 1)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Let:

$$S = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{9^n}{(n + 1)*2^{(2n - 1)}}$$

If I use the Ratio Test to determine whether S converges, I need to 
determine:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| a(n + 1) \div a(n) \right|$$

What is the value of this limit?

[ ]

Using the above answer, we know that S

( ) converges.

( ) diverges.

( ) might converge or diverge; the Ratio Test is inconclusive.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

End Given

Apply Ratio Test:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| a(n + 1)\hspace{1em}\div\hspace{1em}a(n) \right| \\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9^{(n\:+\:1)}}{(n + 1 + 1)*2^{(2(n\:+\:1)\:-\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\div\hspace{1em}\frac
{9^n}{(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}} \right| \tag{1}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9^{(n\:+\:1)}}{(n + 2)*2^{(2n\:+\:2\:-\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\div\hspace{1em}\frac
{9^n}{(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}} \right| \tag{2}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9^{(n\:+\:1)}}{(n + 2)*2^{(2n\:+\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\div\hspace{1em}\frac
{9^n}{(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}} \right| \tag{3}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9^{(n\:+\:1)}}{(n + 2)*2^{(2n\:+\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}\frac
{(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}}{9^n} \right| \tag{4}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9^{(n\:+\:1)}*9^{(-n)}}{(n + 2)*2^{(2n\:+\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}
(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}\right| \tag{5}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9^{(n\:+\:1\:-\:n)}}{(n + 2)*2^{(2n\:+\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}\right| \tag{6}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9^{(1)}}{(n + 2)*2^{(2n\:+\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}\right| \tag{7}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9}{(n + 2)*2^{(2n\:+\:1)}}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}\right| \tag{8}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9}{(n + 2)}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}*2^{-(2n\:+\:1)}\right| \tag{9}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9}{(n + 2)}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1)}*2^{(-2n\:-\:1)}\right| \tag{10}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9}{(n + 2)}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}(n + 1)*2^{(2n\:-\:1\:-\:2n\:-\:1)}\right| \tag{11}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9}{(n + 2)}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}(n + 1)*2^{(-2)}\right| \tag{12}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9}{(n + 2)}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}\frac{(n + 1)}{2^2}\right| \tag{13}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9}{(n + 2)}\hspace{1em}\times\hspace{1em}\frac{(n + 1)}{4}\right| \tag{14}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9(n + 1)}{4(n + 2)} \right| \tag{15}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9n\left(\frac{n}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\right)}{4n\left(\frac{n}{n} + \frac{2}{n} \right)} \right| \tag{16}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left| \frac{9\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)}{4\left(1 + \frac{2}{n} \right)} \right| \tag{17}\\[1em]
\left| \frac{9\left(1 + \frac{1}{\infty}\right)}{4\left(1 + \frac{2}{\infty} \right)} \right| \tag{18}\\[1em]
\left| \frac{9\left(1 + 0\right)}{4\left(1 + 0 \right)} \right| \tag{19}\\[1em]
\left| \frac{9\left(1\right)}{4\left(1\right)} \right| \tag{20}\\[1em]
\left| \frac{9}{4} \right| \tag{21}\\[1em]
\left[\frac{9}{4} \right] \tag{22}\\[1em]
\end{align*}

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}  \left|a(n + 1) \div a(n)\right| < 1$ : converges

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}  \left|a(n + 1) \div a(n)\right| > 1\hspace{1em}or\hspace{1em}= \infty$ : diverges

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}  \left|a(n + 1) \div a(n)\right| = 1$: inconclusive

$\frac{9}{4} > 1$ : [diverges]

### #

Taking directly from their provided solution:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a^{(n+1)}}{a^n}\right|&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{9^{(n+1)}}{(n+2)2^{(2n)}}\cdot\frac{(n+1)2^{(2n−1)}}{9^n} \\[1em]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{9\cdot(n+1)}{(n+2)\cdot2} = \frac{9}{2}\\[1em]
\end{align}

Since the limit is greater than  1, the Ratio Test tells us that the series diverges.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

End of provided solution.

Given the denominator in the leftmost factor, it looks to me that they did: $2^{(2n\:-\:1\:+\:1)}\to2^{(2n)}$

I'm 99% certain that's a mathematically invalid operation.

If I factor the $(2n\:-\:1)$ exponant alone and then add 1, I get this:

\begin{align}
\left(2n\:-\:1\right)\tag{1}\\[1em]
2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{2}\\[1em]
2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\tag{3}\\[1em]
2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{2}\right)\tag{4}\\[1em]
2\left(n\:+\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{5}\\[1em]
\left(2n\:+\frac{2}{2}\right)\tag{6}\\[1em]
\left[\left(2n\:+1\right)\tag{7}\right]\\[1em]
\end{align}

No matter how I work and rework it, I can't get to $(2n)$.

So do I have a case to contest the solution given?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the provided solution has a mistake, $\frac{9}{4}$ is correct.

Comment: I second that..

Comment: I'll present my case forthwith. Thanks boys!

Comment: In step (3) of **your** work (not the *Given* or *provided solution*), you added 1 inside the parentheses. Because the entire expression inside the parentheses was being multiplied by two, you essentially added 2 to the entire expression. Did you mean to do this?

Comment: If you take that into consideration, you end up with $(2n)$.

Comment: @Arturo Don Juan: I don't see the 2n resulting from step 3. In order for it to cancel the -1/2 I'd have to input a +1/2. I'm inputting a 1 or 2/2 which when combined with the -1/2 results in a +1/2, then factor in the 2 I get 2*1/2 = 2/2 = 1. Anyone else see an issue with my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we get $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{9(n+1)}{4(n+2)}$$ thus the searched limit is equal to $$\frac{9}{4}>1$$ thus the sum is divergent

Answer (score 2):

For the question not to remain unanswered: yes, you're right, they're wrong...*but only* in the final ratio obtained. After all, in both ways (yours, the correct one, theirs, the wrong one) the bottom line is the same: the series diverges.

Now, for the sake to write something a little different and way easier in this case: apply Cauchy's $\;n$- th root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{9^n}{(n+1)2^{2n-1}}}=\frac9{\sqrt[n]{n+1}\;2^2\;\sqrt[n]{2^{-1}}}=\frac94\frac{\sqrt[n]2}{\sqrt[n]{n+1}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac94\frac1{1}=\frac94>1$$

and, of course, again we get the same conclusion: the series diverges.

Comment: Yes, the final ratio in either evaluaton does result in the divergent conclusion. However, the actual value of the ratio is a requirement for the problem as given, and my result was counted as incorrect, when in fact it wasn't. Thanks!

Comment: @redthumb I see. Then you should definitely contest the mark given to you.

Answer (score 0):

I will continue my answer here. I will only comment on step (3) from your work (not the *Given* or *provided solution*).

You want to show that $(2n-1+1)\neq(2n)$. You did the following steps.

$$\begin{align*}
\left(2n\:-\:1\right)+1&= 2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}\right)+1\\
&=2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}+1\right)
\end{align*}
$$

The transition from the 2$^{\textrm{nd}}$ to the 3$^{\textrm{rd}}$ step was faulty. If you follow through with it, as you did, you get:

$$\begin{align*}
2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}+1\right) &= 2\left(n\:+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=2n+1
\end{align*}
$$

Which is what you are getting (which seems to be confusing you). The correct way to do follow the steps is.

$$\begin{align*}
\left(2n\:-\:1\right)+1&= 2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}\right)+1\\
&=2\left(n\:-\:\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=2n
\end{align*}
$$

Though all of this work, in my opinion, is far too much for just understanding that $2n-(1-1)=2n-(0)=2n$.

Comment: OK, I see where you are coming from. And as you have worked it, your result is valid. However, in the evaluation of the ratio test, anything "n" will become (n + 1), (n + 2) will become (n + 2 + 1) = (n + 3) and so on. Note 2n would become 2(n + 1). Therefeore if 2n becomes 2(n + 1), then the 2n in (2n ± x) must be evaluated as: (2(n + 1) ± x). Your applied method, though mathematically sound, is out of context for the (n + 1) operation required to evaluate the ratio test. Thanks!